# VSphere API- guestFullName is unset

Tags: python, python-2.7, vsphere

So I'm trying to get the operating systems of all the VMs I've got on VSphere and for some reason some of the VMs operating system is shown as "unset" when pulled from the API (under guestFullName) but in the web panel it shows the OS. I can't find any differences between VMs that I'm able to get the OS info from and the ones I can't get info on. Anyone encountered this?

I'm using the following library https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi

Answer (score 0):

There's two areas where the guestFullName can be sourced, VirtualMachineConfigInfo and VirtualMachineGuestSummary.

The VM Config information is sourced from the VM's VMX file.
The VM Guest Summary information is sourced from the VM guest's VMware Tools instance.

So you may want to double check where you're referencing that property from and whether or not the guests are running VMware Tools.